# Trying to update a row value in SQL with ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: sql, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to update a row value in SQL with my `DbContext` in ASP.NET Core 6. The column is named `TextField` but I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'TextField' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UploadText(string newText, string section)
{
    MgvaKrantransportContext DBContext = new MgvaKrantransportContext();

    var textSelection = DBContext.TextFields.Where(m => m.Section.Equals(section)).ToList();

    TextField newTextField = new TextField();

    foreach (var textField in textSelection)
    {
        newTextField = new TextField() { Id = textField.Id, Section = section, TextContent = newText };
    }

    DBContext.Entry(newTextField).Property(x => x.TextContent).IsModified = true;
    DBContext.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Thanks in advance

Best regards Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to update using a stub entity, don't query the database first.  Simply remove this line

```
 var textSelection = DBContext.TextFields.Where(m => m.Section.Equals(section)).ToList();
```

Alternatively, update the returned TextField(s) and don't create a new one.

eg

```
foreach (var textField in textSelection)
{
    textField.TextContent = newText ;
}
DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to get the Id of the row I am selecting via a non primary key in the database, can I "close" the connection in between maybe?

Comment: You can fetch it with AsNoTracking.  But really you should just update the entity you fetch from the database instead of creating a new one.

Comment: How do I update the entity I fetch from the database or do it with asnotracking?

Comment: See updated answer.